# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n\choose k}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, fractions

I want to prove for any positive integer $n$, the following equation holds:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n\choose k}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k}$$

I tried to expand $2^k$ as $\sum_{i=0}^k{k\choose i}$ and interchange summation, also tried let $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{x^k}{k}$ and compute $f'(x)$. But it seems I'm not on the right path.

Comment: Okay proved (kind of): https://ideone.com/1iyUC5 (died on me at 180).

Comment: See equation (8) of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39228/triple-series-evaluation-delayed/39470#39470

Comment: @Shahar It's quite easy to improve the result. https://ideone.com/ykRJ68

Comment: @user115670: It doesn't matter. And it's far from a proof. The link I gave you contains the proof of your identity.

Comment: @user2345215 I know. Still I have some difficulties on first two steps. Could you please give the answer with more details? Thanks.

Comment: @user115670: Hmm, it seems pretty clear to me. You know you need to read only from the "Now, consider" part of that post, right?

Comment: @user2345215 Why the third line implies the forth in eqn 5?

Comment: Also see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=371496.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that successive terms in the sum on the left turn out have a simple expression for their sum: when $k \ne 0$, we have
$$\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k-1}} + \frac1{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\binom{n+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k-1}\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}}$$

where we've used Pascal's rule and the "absorption" identity that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ for $k \neq 0$. Applying absorption again further gives the above expression to be equal to
$$\frac{\frac{n+1}{k}}{\binom{n}{k}} = \frac{\frac{n+1}{k}}{\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}} = \frac{n+1}{n} \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}$$

This gives a strategy for evaluating the sum on the left:

$$\begin{align}
2\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}} 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k-1}} + \frac1{\binom{n}{k}}\right) + 2 \\
&= 2 + \frac{n+1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}
\end{align}$$
or, calling the left-hand-side sum as $L_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$, we have
$$2 L_n = 2 + \frac{n+1}{n} L_{n-1}$$
$$L_n = \frac{n+1}{2n}L_{n-1} + 1$$

Calling the right-hand-side term $R_n$, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1} R_n &= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{2^k}{k} \\
&= \frac{2^n}{n} R_{n-1} + \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{align}$$
thus
$$R_n = \frac{n+1}{2n}R_{n-1} + 1$$

and both the LHS $L_n$ and RHS $R_n$ satisfy the same recurrence and have the same initial values (check for $n=1$, say), so they are equal.